# Different default push and pull remotes for all branches

Tags: git

For all existing branches in my local repository and new branches I create in my local repository pulling should by default pull from the `origin` remote and pushing should by default push to the `timakro` remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new branch in `git` it doesn't have a "default remote" until you assign one (using, e.g., `git push --set-upstream` or `git branch --set-upstream-to`).

A *remote* can have different *push* and *pull* URLs, so you could do something like:

```
git remote add myremote https://gitserver/for/origin
git remote set-url --push myremote https://otherserver/for/timakro
```

Now if you create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b my_feature_branch
```

And set the upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to myremote
```

Then `git pull` on this branch will pull from the first url, and `git push` will push to the second.

You can make the same change for all existing branches in your repository through the use of a simple shell script to iterate over your local branches and run `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  Maybe something like:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/ |
  awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' |
  xargs -n1 git branch --set-upstream-to myremote
```

Comment: Works perfectly and nice explanation, now I know what was wrong with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`remote set-url`](https://devdocs.io/git/git-remote):

> ### `set-url`
>
> Changes URLs for the remote. Sets first URL for remote `<name>` that
>   matches regex `<oldurl>` (first URL if no  is given) to
>   `<newurl>`. If `<oldurl>` doesn’t match any URL, an error occurs and
>   nothing is changed.
>
> With `--push`, push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs.
>
> With `--add`, instead of changing existing URLs, new URL is added.
>
> With `--delete`, instead of changing existing URLs, all URLs matching
>   regex  are deleted for remote . Trying to delete all
>   non-push URLs is an error.
>
> Note that the push URL and the fetch URL, even though they can be set
>   differently, must still refer to the same place. What you pushed to
>   the push URL should be what you would see if you immediately fetched
>   from the fetch URL. If you are trying to fetch from one place (e.g.
>   your upstream) and push to another (e.g. your publishing repository),
>   use two separate remotes.

---

So, basically:

```
git remote set-url origin <origin-repo>
git remote set-url --push origin <your-own-repo>
```